# Updating a Json Column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns col1,col2 both are json datatype in my table.

col1 has data like this:

```json
[{"a":1},{"b":1}]
```

col2 is having null

I want col2 to be updated as

```json
{"discount":{"1": [{"a":1},{"b":1}]}}
```

To achieve this I have written a query

```
update table_name set col2= jsonb_build_object('discount',  row(col1))
```

But the result in col2 I  am seeing as

```json
{"discount":{"f1": [{"a":1},{"b":1}]}}
```

Instead of "f1" I  want "1"

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: What is `row` meant to achieve? Where should `"1"` come from? Are you saying it needs to correspond to the column name `col1`?

Comment: Just be explicit: `SET col2 = jsonb_build_object('discount', json_build_object('1', col1))`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot, nested jsonb_build_object() worked!!!!